# Getting result as percentage when using foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I currently have a DB with 4 table:

Customer

Sale (CustID & RoomID fk)

Room (ManID fk)

Manager

I am trying to get the cities in which the customers reside in as a percentage. However, I only want to show the the customers who made a purchase using a said manager. Currently this comes through as an amount either under or over 100% total.

When this query is isolated to the customer table, the result adds up to 100% correctly, however it does need to be taken from sales using the manager username as a parameter. This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
(COUNT(c.city) / (SELECT Count(CustID) FROM Customer) * 100) AS percent,     c.city AS City
FROM sale s
INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID
WHERE m.UserName = 'manager123'
GROUP BY c.City;
```

**EDIT:**

I wish to add that the CustID may occur more than once within the sales table, additionally, it may be null. Not sure if is required to use distinct when counting.
Having isolated my issue to this, I felt it necessary to mention as I am still unable to exclude these from the result and an incomplete figure (totaling <100% still showing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution I came to, with a huge thanks to Lim Neo who pointed me in the right direction.

```
SELECT
round(COUNT(c.city) / 
(
    SELECT Count(b.CustID)
    FROM sale s
    INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
    INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
    INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID
    WHERE m.UserName = 'Manager123'
) * 100)
AS percent, c.city AS City
FROM sale s
INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID
WHERE m.UserName = 'Manager123'
GROUP BY c.City;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
SELECT NoCity,COUNT(*)/percent *100 as percentOfCustomerBasedonManager,City
FROM (
SELECT m.UserName,COUNT(c.city) AS NoCity, COUNT(c.CustID) AS percent,c.city AS City FROM
sale s
INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID

GROUP BY c.City ) cityTable WHERE cityTable.UserName = 'manager123'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that puts out 300 & 400 over two columns, could you explain what you are going for? Perhaps I can try to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Please let us know whether it's correct answer. If not correct answer, show the result you may ask for, perhaps we have misunderstanding to interpret your question. Thanks.

Comment: I wish to display a percentage of customers from cities...but only the customers who have made a purchase via a particular manager. Currently is shows for example, 40% and 30% but another 30% unaccounted for

Comment: I try to imagine what you meant for..but I dont get you what you mean puts out 300 & 400 over two columns? Appreciate if we work together to find out answer. :)

Comment: Yes for one city the Percent column in your answer shows 300 and the next columns shows 400...i want the answer shown as percent accumulating to a full 100%...Isolating this to the customer table works as expected, but as mentioned I want to see only customers who made sale with that manager

Comment: I have made some changes, but it's not tested yet. Please let me know whether it works. Thanks.

Comment: Its showing this now Unknown column 'm.UserName' in 'where clause'

Comment: Showed the same issue as above...I tried giving the manager an alias within the sub query and it ran but provided an incomplete percentage again

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
SELECT city, ((city_count)/(customer_count)*100) as Percent
(
    SELECT city, COUNT(*) as city_count, customer_count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT distinct c.city
        FROM sale s
        INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
        INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
        INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID
        WHERE m.UserName = 'manager123'
        GROUP BY c.city
    ) as t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT city as city2, COUNT(*) as customer_count
        FROM
        (
            SELECT c.city, distinct c.CustID
            FROM sale s
            INNER JOIN customer c ON s.CustID = c.CustID
            INNER JOIN room r ON s.RoomID = r.RoomID
            INNER JOIN manager m ON r.ManID = m.ManID
            WHERE m.UserName = 'manager123'
            GROUP BY c.city
        ) as t2
    ) as t3 on t1.city=t3.city2
) as master
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: it seems to have an issue with the opening parenthesis on line 2